# How to create mappings for coc-explorer

Tags: neovim

How to:

1. Check if hidden files are visible
2. Create mappings for F5 showing without hidden files and F6 with hidden files, working in the same time, without changing setings in coc-settings.json
3. Create mappings F7, and F8 for jumping from file to explorers if both explorers are open from point 2